# Arrays two dimensional convert to small array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Have an array arr =

```
[ [1,2] , [5,1], [23,24], [3,4], [22,23], [2,3]]
output needed = [[5,1,2,3,4],[22,23,24]]
```

tried using concat, reduce methods of array in javascript but could not achieve the desired result - any ideas?

Comment: What is the relation between the input array and the output array?

Comment: how in the world do you come up with that needed output?  as a general place to start I would go to https://lodash.com/docs#union but that was just the first method that looked slightly related.  feel free to browse the others listed

Comment: output array is basically - path 1,2 when we see 5 - as we have [5,1] as one of the item 5 goes infront of 1....like wise we create related items by compressing...

Comment: The idea seems to be a PATH. getting the path together... This sure won't be a simple logic..

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by saying the code example and description is not very clear, but I'll take a shot...

It seems you have 3 requirements:

- Flatten the original array.
- Filter out duplicates.
- Group values (somehow?) within the flattened array.

The first 2 tasks on the list can be accomplished using reduce, concat, filter and indexOf methods.

```
var multiArray = [ [1,2] , [5,1], [23,24], [3,4], [22,23], [2,3] ];

var flattened = multiArray.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr);
}, []);

var unique = flattened.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    return array.indexOf(element) === index;
});
```

However, I wont be able to give you an example for that last task until you make it clear how you're hoping to have these values grouped within the flattened array.

I'll update my original answer once clarified.

Comment: Yes, I was able to flatten out using reduce, but in the output - 22,23,24 have to be compresse into a separate array - as they dont have any connections to the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this problem can be solved with more loops and only one array (A) or with an object as reference and only one loop (B).

**A**

An in situ proposal with no object, but with more loops. It checks every array with the path information with each other. If a match is found, the two arrays are

```js
var data = [[1, 2], [5, 1], [23, 24], [3, 4], [22, 23], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
    result = function (data) {
        function first(a) { return a[0]; }
        function last(a) { return a[a.length - 1]; }

        var i = 0, j, t;
        outer: while (i < data.length - 1) {
            j = i + 1;
            while (j < data.length) {
                t = data.splice(j, 1)[0];
                if (first(data[i]) === last(t)) {
                    t.pop();
                    data[i] = t.concat(data[i]);
                    i = 0;
                    continue outer;
                }
                if (last(data[i]) === first(t)) {
                    t.shift();
                    data[i] = data[i].concat(t);
                    i = 0;
                    continue outer;
                }
                data.push(t);
                j++;
            }
            i++
        }
        return data;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

**B**

This is a single loop proposal which takes all parts and appends them if possible. Later all start arrays are returned as result.

```js
var data = [[1, 2], [5, 1], [23, 24], [3, 4], [22, 23], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
    result = function (data) {
        var o = { start: {}, end: {} };
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var temp;
            if (o.end[a[0]]) {
                if (o.start[a[1]] && a[0] !== o.start[a[1]][o.start[a[1]].length - 1] && a[1] !== o.end[a[0]][0]) {
                    temp = o.end[a[0]].concat(o.start[a[1]]);
                    o.start[temp[0]] = temp;
                    o.end[temp[temp.length - 1]] = temp;
                    delete o.start[a[1]];
                } else {
                    o.end[a[1]] = o.end[a[0]];
                    o.end[a[1]].push(a[1]);
                }
                delete o.end[a[0]];
                return;
            }
            if (o.start[a[1]]) {
                o.start[a[0]] = o.start[a[1]];
                o.start[a[0]].unshift(a[0]);
                delete o.start[a[1]];
                return;
            }
            temp = a.slice();
            o.start[a[0]] = temp;
            o.end[a[1]] = temp;
        });
        return Object.keys(o.start).map(function (k) { return o.start[k]; });
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Please check the result when the input is  `[[1, 2], [5, 1], [23, 24], [3, 4], [22, 23], [2, 3], [4,5]]`

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution yet i believe i can make it with less code and more functional. I don't enjoy using `forEach()` or flags like `reduced` much. This one recursively encodes the array items until there is nothing left to encode. Later I will give it another try to make it look more sleek.

```js
var rawarr = [[1,2], [5,1], [23,24], [3,4], [22,23], [2,3]],
  encodarr = (arr) => {
    var reduced = false;
    arr.forEach((c,i,a) => {
      var sa = a.slice(i+1),
      j = sa.findIndex(f => c[0] == f[f.length-1] || c[c.length-1] == f[0]);
      arr[i] = !!~j ? c[0] == sa[j][sa[j].length-1] ? (reduced = true, a.splice(i+j+1,1)[0].concat(c.slice(1)))
                                                    : (reduced = true, c.slice(0,-1).concat(a.splice(i+j+1,1)[0]))
                    : c;
      return arr;
      });
    return reduced ? encodarr(arr) : arr;
  };

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(encodarr(rawarr)) + "</pre>");
```